# Having In-App Notifications Vary By User in IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications, uikit

I am working on in-app notifications for my social media app that I'm programming using Parse and UIKit. My main issue is that while the notification system itself is working, it's not varying by the user.

For example, say there are two users, User1 and User2. The way the notifications should be set up is when User1 likes User2's post or leaves a comment on User2's post, only User2 gets a notification saying "User1 liked your post!" or "User1 left a comment on your post!". However as of right now, when User1 likes or comment's on User2's post, User1 gets the notification.

Here is my code that implements notifications in my app:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var notifications: [PFObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        // Listen for post like events
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didLikePost(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("PostLikedByOtherUser"), object: nil)
        
        // Listen for comment events
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(madeCommentOnPost(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("CommentMade"), object: nil)

        // Configure Notification class on Parse dashboard
        let notificationClass = PFObject(className: "Notification")
        notificationClass["user"] = PFUser.current()
        notificationClass["fromUser"] = PFUser.current()
        notificationClass["post"] = PFObject(className: "Post")
        notificationClass.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if success {
                print("Notification class created successfully")
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error creating notification class: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Query for notifications from Parse
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Notification")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)
        query.includeKey("fromUser")
        query.includeKey("post")
        query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error querying for notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let notifications = objects {
                self.notifications = notifications
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notifications.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotificationCell", for: indexPath) as! NotificationCell

        let notification = notifications[indexPath.row]
        let fromUser = notification["fromUser"] as! PFUser
        let post = notification["post"] as? PFObject

        cell.usernameLabel.text = fromUser.username

        if let username = fromUser.username
        {
            if post != nil
            {
                cell.messageLabel.text = "\(username) liked your post."
            } else
            {
                cell.messageLabel.text = "\(username)left a comment!"
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    @objc func didLikePost(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        guard let post = notification.object as? PFObject,
            let postOwner = post["user"] as? PFUser,
            let liker = notification.userInfo?["liker"] as? PFUser,
            postOwner.objectId != liker.objectId,
            postOwner.objectId != PFUser.current()?.objectId else
        {
                return
        }

        // Create a new notification object
        let notificationObject = PFObject(className: "Notification")
        notificationObject["user"] = postOwner
        notificationObject["fromUser"] = liker
        notificationObject["post"] = post

        notificationObject.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if success
            {
                print("Successfully created notification")
            } else if let error = error
            {
                print("Error creating notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    // Called when a comment is made
    @objc func madeCommentOnPost(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        guard let comment = notification.object as? PFObject,
            let post = comment["post"] as? PFObject,
            let postOwner = post["user"] as? PFUser,
            let commenter = notification.userInfo?["commenter"] as? PFUser,
            postOwner.objectId != commenter.objectId,
            postOwner.objectId != PFUser.current()?.objectId else
        {
                return
        }

        // Create a new notification object
        let notificationObject = PFObject(className: "Notification")
        notificationObject["user"] = postOwner
        notificationObject["fromUser"] = commenter
        notificationObject["post"] = post

        notificationObject.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if success
            {
                print("Successfully created notification")
            } else if let error = error
            {
                print("Error creating notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    deinit
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

As always, all help is greatly appreciated!